# Php script sync

Tags: php, multithreading, synchronization

I need to launch some php script in background (without waiting)and then wait until all processes are terminated,something(if you are familiar with multithreading)similar to a barrier.

Example:

```
//...code...

run_script('myscript1.php');//it's like an exec but doesen't wait for the script to finish
run_script('myscript2.php');//it's like an exec but doesen't wait for the script to finish
run_script('myscript3.php');//it's like an exec but doesen't wait for the script to finish

do_something();

wait_until_all_proc_are_finished();//it will wait until all script are executed
do_something_else();
//....
```

I created a script that should do the trick;i tested it in console and it works nice but it doesen't work on php pages,i don't understand why!

```
class TSync{
    private $threads=array();
    function tcreate($p){
            $tname=tempnam(null,'THS_');//create a temp name               

            $p=addslashes($p);//just to be sure

            $name=addslashes($tname);

            $ex= 'php -r "$fp=fopen(\''.$name.'\',\'r+\');flock($fp,LOCK_EX);include(\''.$p.'\');fclose($fp);"';

            run_on_background($ex);//execute it on background      

            $this->threads[count($this->threads)]=$tname;

            return count($this->threads)-1;//returns the thread "id"

    }
    function twait($id){
        $f=$this->threads[$id];//recover the name
        /***even this doesen't work***
        $fp=fopen($f,'r');
        flock($fp,LOCK_EX);
        fclose($fp);   
        */
        echo date("H:i:s"),"#Locking on $f<br/>";

        $ex= 'php -r "$fp=fopen(\''.$f.'\',\'r\');flock($fp,LOCK_EX);fclose($fp);"';

        exec($ex);
        unlink($f);

    }


}

$t=new TSync();//create the class

$f=$t->tcreate(dirname(__FILE__).'/testth.php');//this is a test script that waits 10s
$t->twait($f);//now you should wait the script,commenting this line should result on the script not waiting
```

An example of the effective code launched on console (tested on windows)

```
start /b php.exe -r "$fp=fopen('C:\\Windows\\Temp\\THS6D7.tmp','w');flock($fp,LOCK_EX);include('C:/.../testth.php');fclose($fp);"
```

If i launch the code multiple times the second script will wait the first so it should work.

Comment: so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: asking why it doesn't work when used in the context of a web page (rather than the CLI)

Comment: Ben is right:
the code i posted should do what i asked but in php doesen't work and i don't know why;
if you can fix it or post some other solution please do.
Anyway i recently discovered that the php version i'm using(5.3.0)unlock the resource on fclose (php >5.3.2 doesen't do that anymore),i don't know if updating may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this by using [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

Comment: it's a php extension,it's not php code;also my code should (theorically)work but it doesen't so if anyone can tell me why it doesen't work it's already perfect.